# Why won't my HTML search bar produce results after querying an XML file?

Tags: python, html, xml, database, flask

I have an XML with places like bars, groceries and restaurants (Name, Address, Description, Establishment-Type and so on) and I'd like to create a simple HTML website with a search bar, which allows users to search for keywords such as "bars" or "groceries" and returns a list of places from the XML that contains these words in the "Establishment-type" child-element of the place. The "root element" in CATALOG and "row element" is PLACES.

The question: With this code, when I search for "bars" in the created Search Bar, it is not displaying any results - makes me think it is either (1) not querying the XML successfully or (2) querying properly but not displaying on the HTML. Does my code suggest that either one is the problem (or both)?

(note that if you run this you have to add "/views/" to the generated URL on VSCode)

here's a short version of my places.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
  <PLACES>
    <Name>XXX</Name>
    <Rating>3.4</Rating>
    <Reviews>329</Reviews>
    <Category>Discount supermarket</Category>
    <Description>In-store shopping</Description>
    <Address>XXX</Address>
    <phoneNumber>XXX</phoneNumber>
    <Establishment-Type>Groceries</Establishment-Type>
  </PLACES>
  <PLACES>
    <Name>YYY</Name>
    <Rating>3.8</Rating>
    <Reviews>208</Reviews>
    <Category>Grocery store</Category>
    <Description>In-store shopping</Description>
    <Address>YYY</Address>
    <phoneNumber>YYY</phoneNumber>
    <Establishment-Type>Groceries</Establishment-Type>
  </PLACES>
```

Here is the HTML code (stored in a folder called 'Templates' in the root directory):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Come live with us</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <br>
            <label for="search">Search Establishments:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
            <br>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>

            {% if establishments %}
               <h2>Search Results:</h2>
               <ul>
                   {% for places in establishments %}
                      <li>{{ places.name }} - {{ places.address }}</li>
                   {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Python and Flask to create this site. Here is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask
from views import views

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/views")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

And views.py (to avoid clutter on app.py):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request

views = Blueprint(__name__, "views")

@views.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_query = request.form.get('search')
        # Perform search logic with the XML file
        establishments = search_establishments(search_query)
        return render_template("apt.html", establishments=establishments)
    else:
        return render_template("apt.html")

def search_establishments(query):
    # Parse the XML file
    tree = ET.parse('apt\places.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    # Perform the search based on the query
    establishments = []
    for places in root.findall('PLACES'):
        establishment_type = places.find('Establishment-Type').text
        if establishment_type.lower() == query.lower():
            establishment = {
                'name': places.find('Name').text,
                'address': places.find('Address').text
            }
            establishments.append(establishment)

    return establishments

#@views.route("/")
#def home():
    #return render_template("apt.html")
```